# Google Sheets - Sort results of query by column B (count)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, sorting

I have this query

```
=QUERY({'2008'!A2:A500;'2009'!A2:A500;'2010'!A2:A500;'2011'!A2:A500;'2012'!A2:A500;'2013'!A2:A1000;'2014'!A2:A1000;'2015'!A2:A1000;'2016'!A2:A1000;'2017'!A2:A1000;'2018'!A2:A1000;'2019'!A2:A1000;'2020'!A2:A1000},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label Col1 'Name', count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

It pulls results from numerous tabs and tells me how many times the same title appears across the years. But it displays it alphabetically by name. Like this:

```
A 1
B 4
C 2
D 5
```

I want it to display using the count result in descending order.

```
D 5 
B 4 
C 2 
A 1
```

Everything I try results in an error, and the basic sort by column B instantly reverts back to the original view.

Comment: did you try "order by Count desc"?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I'm still getting a parse error, so I must be doing something wrong, When you get a chance could clarify where that should go in the query?

Comment: first of all, not sure why there are quotation marks after 'where Col1 !=' in your formula. that seems to break the formula string. try removing that.

Answer (score 2):

The `select` clause identifies "Col1" and "count(Col1)". So try `order by` on "count(Col1)":

`"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) label Col1 'Name', count(Col1) 'Count'"`